# How to add button click event with a callback function in javascript as window.confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

First question here, Newbie on Stackoverflow, so if there is anything which I have missed, please guide me.my question is as follows,

I am creating a custom popup message like window.confirm. In the function user need to pass some of the arguments like Msg header, content and type of the message along with a callback function which will execute when user click on the buttons on the popup.

For creating popup I have written below code:

```
 function CreatePopupMessage(IsConfirm,ContentMsg,Headertext,WithoutHeader,callbackFunction){    
    var popupHtml = '<div class="modal-dialog">';
    popupHtml += '<div class="modal-content">';
    if(WithoutHeader == true){
        popupHtml += '<button type="button" class="close" style="position:absolute;z-index:9999;right:0;margin-right:10px;margin-top:2px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
    }
    else{
        popupHtml += '<div class="modal-header">';
        popupHtml += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
        popupHtml += '<h4 class="popup-header-text">'+Headertext+'</h4>';
        popupHtml += '</div>';
    }
    popupHtml += '<div class="modal-body">';
    popupHtml += '<p>'+ContentMsg+'</p>';
    popupHtml += '</div>';
    popupHtml += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    popupHtml += '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="okBtnPress" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ok</button>';
    if(IsConfirm == true){
        popupHtml += '<button class="btn btn-default" id="cancelBtnPress" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>';
    }        
    popupHtml += '</div>';
    popupHtml += '</div>';
    popupHtml += '</div>'; 

    $('div#Timed_CustomPopupModel').html(popupHtml);

    // Callback function Which will be executed
   // NEED HELP HERE TO WORK OUT HOW TO ATTACH THE BUTTON CLICK WITH THE CALLBACK FUNCTION AS ARGUMENT
      callbackFunction(argument); // Argument should be the single which will tell user that on which button user has been clicked , like in windo.confirm we get 'true' when we click OK button and get 'false ' when we click 'Cancel' button

 }
```

Now I just want to pass some simple arguments which will create the popup and show that to user, now when user click any of the button in the popup the callback function which is created by user should called and it will pass a argument which will tell result, which contains either true or false as window.confirm.

so my callback function which I will pass in my popup Message will look like this:

```
 function onPopupButtonClicked(result){
     if(result == true){
        // Ok button pressed in the popup, please perform this
     }
     else if(result == false){
        // Cancel button pressed in the popup, please perform this
     }
 }

 // Call the popup generate function 
  CreatePopupMessage(true,'Confirm With the Operation?','Confirm',false,onPopupButtonClicked);
```

As we execute this code it will show the popup and when we click on any of the button our callback function **onPopupButtonClicked** will called. See the generated popup will look like that:
[Popup Message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1x8u.png)

Please help me how can I achieve this functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bootstrap modal for this. In the modal, You can do whatever inputs you need then a 'submit' btn which will have a JQuery handler when clicked. You can then get the textbox values, do whatever you need to do, and then execute the callback (or whatever).

the JQuery code would be like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnId').click(function(cb){
    //Do whatever you need to do here
  })
})
```

and HTML:

```
<input ... />
<input ... />
<button id='btnId'>Submit</button>
```

EDIT:

After some clarification, I now understand the question. Please see below for solution:

To do this the modal would have to be generated dynamically for each Modal, then on the delete button all you would add is the Modal open, it wouldn't actually start to delete the record. On the confirm, the 'Yes' button would  execute your deletion code. The cancel button would just... well, cancel. To do this you would need a Modal tree of 2 modals, the outer one for the Delete window (or whatever), and the inner one for the confirm window.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap already, and this particular function will create the popup in bootstrap style, my question is I want to make it as generic so I can use it anywhere and the callback function will be defined by me, which will execute my logic based on user action(popup button pressed). my concern is how can I add the button press event as the argument of the callback, and that callback should be executed when user press any of the button. I hope you understand

Comment: So wait, you want to create a popup when someone clicks a popup button?

Comment: Understand it by this scenario, user going to delete certain record from UI, as user clicked on delete button this popup came which will generated run-time with the user scenario and then if user click on OK, the deletion code will execute, like window.confirm. this is just the one scenario, in my application there are hundreds of other scenarios when custom popup will created run-time and based on the button click the next operation will going to perform.

Comment: Actually that thing I have already handled that popup as modal window. my concern is regarding the callback where somehow I can add a parameter which tell me which action user has been chosen.

Comment: @user2809299 Ah I see, so your parent Modal isn't just for deletion?

Comment: yes,Popup will be created run-time, means every time a new popup message will created from the function and new callback function also need to create to manage the further action on the popup.

Answer (score 0):

When your modal is opened you want to bind a value to each button, `true` when `OK` is clicked and `false` when `CANCEL` is clicked. 
So use the function below as your callback.

```
function onPopupButtonClicked(){
    $(document).on('click','#okBtnPress',function() {
    alert('true'); // TRUE
    });
    $(document).on('click','#cancelBtnPress',function() {
    alert('false'); // TRUE
    });
}
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6o6wzyox/)

Comment: Peter, thanks for pointing it, well I can use that, but in that case every time for each popup I need to repeat that piece of code where you bounding the click event for the button press, I want to add or bind this thing somehow in that function `CreatePopupMessage` itself, so on the callback function side I just need to check that argument which is coming as true and false, based on button click. Hope you get the context.

Comment: does working with localStorage mind you? @user2809299

Comment: Didn't get you, Can you please explain

Comment: pass the variable value to localStorage and check it from there. If something is set in localStorage it can be removed only if you close your browser or remove the item the way you have set it, via javascript. Check this example. http://jsbin.com/dexogufagi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: No, I don't think so it will work, I have seen few posts and get a idea would like to share with you, Can we add the bind event function as a parameter in the callback function means in the `CreatePopupMessage` function we will add the callback function with the parameters and in the parameter we add the button click bind event, so whenever button clicked the callback function called and it will bind the button click event as argument, like Ok clicked or Cancel Clicked